# I want to show message box when application is crashed by memory depletion

Tags: c++, windows

I want to show message box when application is crashed by memory depletion.

But there are not enough memory.

Memory exception occurs again in exception handling function

I used windows API MessageBoxW function

```
MessageBoxW(
    __in_opt HWND hWnd,
    __in_opt LPCWSTR lpText,
    __in_opt LPCWSTR lpCaption,
    __in UINT uType);
```

Is there way to make message box in advance?

If possible, I can just show it when application is crashed by memory depletion.

Is there good solution?

Comment: If you run out of memory telling the user about it should not be your first priority. Your first priority is trying to find the memory leak. Besides, if the system is so low on memory you can't even display a message box, the user probably knows there's something wrong anyway since the system will crawl to a halt as it just keeps on swapping.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Theoretically there is a situation when the application may run out its virtual memory without a destabilized OS - when the application is 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system and the user has more than 4GB RAM installed on his computer. It may be possible that the user doesn't notice anything besides the crash. I agree with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a wrapping processwhich starts your program as the child process and waits for its exit. You need to think how to return the error code from the child process when the memory is over. When the child process is terminated, the parent should analyze the exit code and decide whether to show the error message or not. Note. This will work if the out of memory happens because of your program. Then, upon its exiting all the memory is returned to the OS and your parent process can emmit the message. Otherwise you need to reserve the required amount of the memory at your parent process upon its starting. Hope this strategy helps.